# Explanation on References and Borrowing from The Rust book

Tags: rust

I'm reading the Rust book and References and Borrowing in Chapter 4 seems to be inconsistent to me.
In [Reference and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html), figure 4-5 below shows that `s` points to `s1` instead of the actual data on the heap.

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");

    let len = calculate_length(&s1);

    println!("The length of '{}' is {}.", s1, len);
}

fn calculate_length(s: &String) -> usize {
    s.len()
}
```

[image: Figure 4-5: A diagram of &String s pointing at String s1]

But in [String Slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#string-slices), the diagram clearly shows that `world` references the actual data, though only part of it. It also says that the following code "is similar to taking a reference to the whole String but with the extra [0..5] bit. Rather than a reference to the entire String, it’s a reference to a portion of the String."

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello world");

    let hello = &s[0..5];
    let world = &s[6..11];
}
```

And here is the diagram (figure4-6) that explains the above code:
[image: String slice referring to part of a String]

Now I guess my question is why isn't `world` referring to `s` in the String Slices case? I understand that `world` can't just point to `s` because then it would not be able to get the last 5 letters. But these two diagrams seem completely different to me, yet they are all "references". Can someone please provide a logical way to understand it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what does a `&[mut] String` guarantee in a safe context?

- That there is a `String` behind the pointer, which therefore supports your first diagram.

Then, what does a `&[mut] str` guarantee in a safe context?

- The same idea as a `String`, that there is a [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) behind the pointer. But what does that mean? What really is an `str`?

According to the docs page:

> A &str is made up of two components: a pointer to some bytes, and a length.

Meaning, that the `&str` really is a pointer to some valid utf-8 and a length, so really, a `str` is the data itself, and *not* the `String`. The `String` can be regarded as a manipulable `str`. So the `&my_string[..]` is really a pointer/reference to the data under the `String`.

Comment: Thanks Optimistic Peach. I think I understand what you're saying. So can I understand it this way: &s[0..5] first gets s[0..5] as a `str`, in this case the 'world' string, and then use & to get the pointer/reference to it?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to say, the `String` and the `&str` both refer to the same data, it just happens to be that the `&str` points to the data directly, instead of going through the `String`, while the `String` actually owns the internal `str`.

Comment: I do understand that `String` and `&str` both refer to the same data. I guess what's hard for me to understand was the part when you said "it just **happens** to be that the `&str` points to the data directly" because in the first diagram it shows that `&String` points to the `String` but in the second example, `s` is still `String`, the only thing that was different was that the example used `&s[0..5]` and my understanding was that you are treating `&s[0..5]` as `&str`, which led to my understanding that `s[0..5]` returns a `str` and then we use `&` to refer to it. Thanks :p

Comment: Okay I think I'm wrong. I was thinking that there is operation precedence in `&s[0..5]` but apparently it's not the case. When `s` is `String`, I can't do `s[0..5]`. So `&s[0..5]` must be happen at once and return a `&str`, and just like you said, it just happens that the `&str` points to the data directly (probably a design choice).

Comment: Yes, `s[..]` amounts to an `str`, because an `str` is the actual data, there is no separation between the `str` and the raw continuous bytes that make up the data, but it must be kept behind a pointer because it doesn't have a known size and therefore cannot live on the stack, `String` is a "smart" pointer over `str` which can reallocate and change size

Answer (score 0):

A reference to a string and a string slice are different things, so it is normal that they are represented differently.

Most of the time a string slice is more useful, because you can refer to substrings, which makes it more flexible. Generally a function parameter for reading some string data should be a string slice and not a reference to a string.

Also, [you can use an actual parameter of type `&String` for a string slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref):

> Strings implement Deref, and so inherit all of str's
>   methods. In addition, this means that you can pass a String to a
>   function which takes a &str by using an ampersand (&)

One useful thing you can't do with a slice is increasing the size of a string, in that case you need a mutable reference to the string. An example is the [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.read_line) function, which appends string data to `buf`:

> `pub fn read_line(&self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize>`

Comment: "Most of the time a string slice is more useful, because you can refer to substrings, which makes it more flexible." ??? string can do that too, that actually how you create a str from a string.